# "Out of my league" expression avoiding romantic connotations

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

E.g. (while discussing the merits of some software developing issue with a co worker):

> I won't argue with you since you're out of my league.

I used to think of "out of one's league" to refer to anything, not only to refer to someone one has no chance of dating. But it seems like it's being used mainly for that purpose (today? Always has been?).

**Is there an alternative expression** which will not cause misunderstandings, or perhaps I'm wrong and this one won't either?

I do realize that it still doesn't *have* to mean that. But I'm worried that saying that might be misinterpreted as a hint implying something to that effect.

(Should there be a "misunderstanding" tag?)

**EDIT**

Since I'm being asked why do I even think it might have the above-mentioned connotation, here are the top Google results for "out of my league expression": (I'm not signed in to Google and I have history turned off in Google settings.)

[Featured snippet](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/someone-something-is-out-of-someone-s-league): "...She was the most beautiful girl in school, and I knew she was out of my league.".

[First result](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Out%20of%20my%20league): "A person you have no chance with dating/hooking up with because they are considered much more attractive,..."

[Then comes the "People also ask"'s first question](https://www.quora.com/What-exactly-does-out-of-my-league-mean): "What does it mean when someone says your way out of my league? It's an expression used usually in a romantic context. “I like Alice, but she's out of my league” ..."

[Then comes the second result (Quora)'s first result](https://www.quora.com/What-exactly-does-out-of-my-league-mean) which is the same as the previous.

[Then comes the Featured snippet as a result](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/someone-something-is-out-of-someone-s-league) (see above).

[Then comes the next result](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+out+of+my+league), the first example of which is: "I can't believe that average-looking guy is dating a supermodel—she is totally out of his league!".

[Then comes an almost identical result to the previous result](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Out+of+My+League).

[Then comes the next result](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/stop-saying-he-or-she-is-out-of-your-league_b_5022104) **titled**: "Stop Saying He (Or She) Is Out Of Your League".

So all of the above are mentioned in a romantic setting, sometimes with emphasis.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98414/discussion-on-question-by-ispiro-out-of-my-league-expression-avoiding-romantic).

Answer (score 1):

**"Punching above one's weight"**   which means

> "Competing against someone who you are no match for."

See https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/290900.html for more.

Comment: All instances of "punching above one's weight" I have seen were about situations where someone was competing against ostensibly stronger opposition AND winning or otherwise being successful. Even example in link you provided is about comedian who after becoming famous, could attract partners more attractive than his looks alone would let him.

Answer (score 0):

Use of the expression you cite does not primarily have romantic connotations, but, in any case, the best thing to do is to say what you mean in plain English.

e.g.

> I won’t argue with you because you know more about [*name of subject*
>   *matter*] than I do.

or

> I won’t argue with you because you’re the expert (on this).

(And if you want an alternative romantic expression, you could try “She’s too classy for you”, but in general I would advise against using slang expressions if you are not master of the language. In any case they vary with region, age, and social class.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98415/discussion-on-answer-by-david-out-of-my-league-expression-avoiding-romantic-co).